# Cannot get a user function to co-operate with a subquery in mariadb

Tags: join, mariadb, functions, subquery

The following is a demo of an issue we are having with a function and a subquery. I'm interested to know if it is a bug or if there is a reasonable explaination why it is failing.

Notes:

- Problem only in MariaDB, not in MySQL.
- We are using version 10.3.13 of MariaDB.
- Issue shows in both Gentoo and Debian distros.
- If a constant is used instead of the function, it behaves.
- If a list is used instead of the subquery, it behaves.
- In our testing on the real application, multiple JOINs (with or without LEFT) also broke the query.

Why is the JOIN affecting the result at all?

```sql
USE `test`;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `pastPosition`;
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `pastPosition`(`who` INT(11), `when` DATE) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `result` int(11);
    SELECT `position_id` INTO `result`
        FROM `position_history`
        WHERE `when`>=`from` AND `when`<=`to` AND `employee_id`=`who`;
    RETURN `result`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `employee` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `division_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `employee` VALUES 
    (1, 'Mrs Robinson', 2),
    (2, 'Joe DiMaggio', 2),
    (3, 'Paul Simon', 1),
    (4, 'Art Garfunkel', 1)
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `position` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `position_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `is_management` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `position` VALUES 
    (1, 'Grand Poobah', 1),
    (2, 'Average Poobah', 1),
    (3, 'Serf', 0)
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `position_history` (
    `from` DATE NOT NULL,
    `to` DATE NOT NULL,
    `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `position_id` int(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `position_history` VALUES 
    ('1972-01-01','1988-12-31', 3, 1),
    ('1972-01-01','1988-12-31', 4, 1),
    ('1972-01-01','1988-12-31', 1, 2),
    ('1972-01-01','1988-12-31', 2, 3)
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `division` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `division` VALUES 
    (1, 'Songwriter'),
    (2, 'Song Character')
;

SELECT '  employees in management in 1980:' AS 'WITH_LEFT_JOIN';
SELECT *
    FROM `employee`
    LEFT JOIN `division` ON `employee`.`division_id` = `division`.`id`
    WHERE pastPosition(`employee`.`id`, '1980-01-01') IN
        (SELECT `id` FROM `position` WHERE `is_management`=1);

SELECT '  employees in management in 1980:' AS 'WITH_JOIN';
SELECT *
    FROM `employee`
    JOIN `division` ON `employee`.`division_id` = `division`.`id`
    WHERE pastPosition(`employee`.`id`, '1980-01-01') IN
        (SELECT `id` FROM `position` WHERE `is_management`=1);
```

results on mysql, (working):

```
WITH_LEFT_JOIN
  employees in management in 1980:
id      name    division_id     id      name
1       Mrs Robinson    2       2       Song Character
3       Paul Simon      1       1       Songwriter
4       Art Garfunkel   1       1       Songwriter
WITH_JOIN
  employees in management in 1980:
id      name    division_id     id      name
1       Mrs Robinson    2       2       Song Character
3       Paul Simon      1       1       Songwriter
4       Art Garfunkel   1       1       Songwriter
```

results on mariadb, (not working):

```
WITH_LEFT_JOIN
  employees in management in 1980:
WITH_JOIN
  employees in management in 1980:
id      name    division_id     id      name
1       Mrs Robinson    2       2       Song Character
3       Paul Simon      1       1       Songwriter
4       Art Garfunkel   1       1       Songwriter
```

---

Here is the EXPLAIN SELECT outputs:

### LEFT JOIN

MySQL (working):

```
+----+--------------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | employee | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | division | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | position | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Maridb (non-working):

```
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                           |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | employee    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    4 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | eq_ref | distinct_key  | distinct_key | 4       | func |    1 | Using where                                     |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | division    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    2 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | position    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where                                     |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "employee",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "rows": 4,
      "filtered": 100
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "<subquery2>",
      "access_type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": ["distinct_key"],
      "key": "distinct_key",
      "key_length": "4",
      "used_key_parts": ["id"],
      "ref": ["func"],
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "pastPosition(employee.`id`,'1980-01-01') = position.`id`",
      "materialized": {
        "unique": 1,
        "query_block": {
          "select_id": 2,
          "table": {
            "table_name": "position",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "rows": 3,
            "filtered": 100,
            "attached_condition": "position.is_management = 1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "block-nl-join": {
      "table": {
        "table_name": "division",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows": 2,
        "filtered": 100
      },
      "buffer_type": "flat",
      "buffer_size": "256Kb",
      "join_type": "BNL",
      "attached_condition": "trigcond(pastPosition(employee.`id`,'1980-01-01') = position.`id`) and trigcond(division.`id` = employee.division_id)"
    }
  }
}
```

### JOIN

MySQL (working):

```
+----+--------------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                          |
+----+--------------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | division | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    2 |                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | employee | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | position | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where                    |
+----+--------------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------+
```

MariaDB (working):

```
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table       | type   | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                           |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | division    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    2 |                                                 |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | employee    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join) |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | eq_ref | distinct_key  | distinct_key | 4       | func |    1 | Using where                                     |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | position    | ALL    | NULL          | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where                                     |
+------+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "division",
      "access_type": "ALL",
      "rows": 2,
      "filtered": 100
    },
    "block-nl-join": {
      "table": {
        "table_name": "employee",
        "access_type": "ALL",
        "rows": 4,
        "filtered": 100
      },
      "buffer_type": "flat",
      "buffer_size": "256Kb",
      "join_type": "BNL",
      "attached_condition": "employee.division_id = division.`id`"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "<subquery2>",
      "access_type": "eq_ref",
      "possible_keys": ["distinct_key"],
      "key": "distinct_key",
      "key_length": "4",
      "used_key_parts": ["id"],
      "ref": ["func"],
      "rows": 1,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "pastPosition(employee.`id`,'1980-01-01') = position.`id`",
      "materialized": {
        "unique": 1,
        "query_block": {
          "select_id": 2,
          "table": {
            "table_name": "position",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "rows": 3,
            "filtered": 100,
            "attached_condition": "position.is_management = 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks worthy of a bug report to me. https://jira.mariadb.org

Comment: Please provide 4 `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (one per case per server).  And, if available, `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: I've added the EXPLAINS for MariaDB to the question.  MySQL coming soon.  I'm new to EXPLAIN SELECT, so I'll be working through the output too.

Comment: MySQL explations are up. (It is running v5.5 which doesn't include the FORMAT=JSON option.  I could spin up a later version if needed.)

Comment: Starting to agree with @danblack . Submitted a bug. (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19580)

Answer (score 1):

This has been confirmed as a bug:

[Unrelated JOINs corrupt usage of 'WHERE function() IN (subquery)'](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19580)